# Working with dates in linq to xml

Tags: datagridview, linq-to-xml

I would please like to retrieve data from a xml file based on user input with date. I would like to compare the user input date with the date in the xml file and if its greater than the xml file date, it should retrieve it. my linq query looks like this thanks in advance.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("xml/data1.xml"));

var hotels = from hotel in xmlDoc.Descendants("Table")
             where Double.Parse(pplTextBox.Text) <= Double.Parse(hotel.Element("NO_OF_PEOPLE").Value) && 
             DateTime.Parse(DateTextFrom.Text) > DateTime.Parse(hotel.Element("DATE_TO").Value)
             select new
             {
                RoomCost = hotel.Element("ROOM_COST").Value,
                RoomType = hotel.Element("ROOM_TYPE").Value,
                HotelName = hotel.Element("HOTEL_NAME").Value,
                NoOfPeople = hotel.Element("NO_OF_PEOPLE").Value,
                Smoking = hotel.Element("SMOKING").Value,
                Restaurant = hotel.Element("RESTAURANT").Value,
                //Location = hotel.Element("HOTEL_AREA").Value,
                //AvailableDate = hotel.Element("DATE_TO").Value
             };

    GridView1.DataSource = hotels.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yes - and what is the problem? You seem to be checking for the Date in your XLINQ query already.  What's your question then?

Comment: there is an error when the date is selected from the user end and when the check availability is pressed to retrieve; it gives a datetime parse error. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: WHAT does the user enter? What string? It's probably really only a string-to-DateTime conversion problem that has nothing to do with Linq-To-XML at all.......

Comment: when the user selects the date from the calendar, it is viewed in a textbox which is used in the linq query as DateTextFrom.

Answer (score 0):

can you use?

```
AvailableDate = (hotel.Element("DATE_TO").Value > inputDate) ? 
                     hotel.Element("DATE_TO").Value : inputDate
```